# If : second conditional inversion

Tags: conditional-constructions, inversion

teachers!

I'd like to ask you something about conditional inversion.

I'd like to know my sentence is right.

I changed the sentence ' If you were able to see ...' to ' Were you able to see..'

I tried 2nd conditional inversion and I wonder my sentence is correct.

Thank you!

Comment: "Were you able" is in the subjunctive mood.

Comment: No it isn't. It is, exactly as the OP said, the literary inverted form of the conditional "If you were able to see".

Comment: @ColinFine: Really? Then the "uninverted" conditional "it were not" would make sense without the subjunctive mood?

Comment: @ColinFine You're both talking about more or less the same thing. The second conditional _is_ subjunctive + "would" + base form of verb. The literary inverted form is still subjunctive and drops the "if."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. That is exactly right. I'm sure you realise that this inversion is a literary form, little used in speech.